# PSpice VSIN frequency - how to set it in rad/s?

Tags: voltage, simulation, spice, orcad, cadence

I know, that if I want to set FREQ, I need to set it in Hz, not in rad/s. I know, that

1 Hz = 2*pi rad/s,

but how to do this in PSpice? What should I enter exactly?

and btw. if I want to set VOFF (voltage offset), I need to pass it in volts, not an angle. How to convert it, so I could pass angle as an offet?

Comment: No, rad/sec = 2*Pi*F(Hz).

Comment: @Andyaka: Huh? I thought spinning a wheel at 1 rotation/second (i.e., at 1 Hz) was the same as spinning a wheel at an angular velocity of 2*pi radians/second. So 1 Hz == 2pi rad/s.

Comment: As you originally had the formula (before the edit) I thought it was incorrect. It's changed now so either it was wrong or I was stupid!!

Comment: @Andyaka :-) Yeah, it was ambiguous.

Comment: Use .param and declare the conversion in the statement. You can use the param variable for both FREQ and VOFF. But could you explain more meticulously what you actually mean by angle

Comment: *"...if I want to set VOFF (voltage offset), I need to pass it in volts, not an angle..."* - of course you have to, because it is a **VOLTAGE** offset! It has **nothing** in common with an angle; it's an independent parameter of the VSIN source.
So your requirement *"How to convert it, so I could pass angle as an offset?"* does not give any sense...